# Cannot access custom view during UI Testing in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

In my app there is a label which is contained inside a simple view.
The view has a tap recogniser which will trigger a function ("why not using a button?" you might ask..well, we had to perform some funky animation and that was our best layout to do it). The problem is that I cannot access this view for simulating a tap on it.
I can access the label with `app.staticText["Enter name..."]` but if I tap on it (hoping in a propagation to the parent view).
Recording a session where I tap on the label will product an `app.staticText["Enter name..."]` command but playing it back products the same error.

I have tried activating the Accessibility flat for that view in the Storyboard and giving it an ID in order to get it by using this command:

```
app.windows.elementMatchingType(.Any, identifier: "MyView")
```

but as soon this flag is checked and I run my test the app enters a sort of loop of loop displaying this message over and over:

```
Find: Elements matching predicate '"MyView" IN identifiers'
```

This view is not inside a table but in the main View. How can I gain access to it?

EDIT 1:
this is the output of app.DebugDescription() (thanks to @Che for the advice):

```
    Element subtree:
 →Application 0x14e7e300: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
    Window 0x14dbfef0: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
      Other 0x14dc0a40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
        Other 0x14dc0ff0: traits: 8589934592
        Other 0x14eb4f50: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
          Other 0x14eb53d0: traits: 8589934592
          Button 0x14eb5940: traits: 8589934593, {{12.0, 26.0}, {30.0, 30.0}}, label: 'home hamburger'
            Image 0x14eb5f00: traits: 8589934596, {{16.0, 30.0}, {22.0, 22.0}}, identifier: 'home_hamburger'
          Other 0x14eb64c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 109.0}, {320.0, 459.0}}
          Other 0x14eb6a20: traits: 8589934592, {{16.0, 167.0}, {288.0, 84.0}}
          Image 0x14eb6f80: traits: 8589934596, {{59.0, 184.0}, {201.0, 50.0}}, identifier: 'main_logo'
          Other 0x14eb4850: traits: 8589934592, {{16.0, 254.0}, {288.0, 60.0}}
            StaticText 0x14eb79e0: traits: 8589934656, {{57.0, 264.0}, {160.0, 40.0}}, label: 'Enter name...'
            Image 0x14eb7f90: traits: 8589934596, {{31.0, 275.0}, {18.0, 18.0}}, identifier: 'SearchIcon'
            Other 0x14eb8530: traits: 8589934592, {{57.0, 274.0}, {2.0, 20.0}}
          Other 0x14eb8ac0: traits: 8589934592, {{16.0, 262.0}, {288.0, 44.0}}
            Image 0x14eb9060: traits: 8589934596, {{16.0, 262.0}, {288.0, 44.0}}
            SearchField 0x14eb9610: traits: 146029151232, {{24.0, 270.0}, {272.0, 28.0}}
          Other 0x14eb9bc0: traits: 8589934592
        Other 0x14eba170: traits: 8589934592
    Window 0x14eba730: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
      StatusBar 0x14ebaca0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}
        Other 0x14ebb220: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}
        Other 0x14ebb7b0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}
          Other 0x14ebbd50: traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {35.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 5 bars, signal strength'
          Other 0x14ebc330: traits: 8388608, {{44.0, 0.0}, {73.0, 20.0}}, label: 'vodafone UK network'
          Other 0x14ebc8c0: traits: 8388608, {{122.0, 0.0}, {13.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID
          Other 0x14ebce50: traits: 8389120, {{146.0, 0.0}, {32.0, 20.0}}, label: '11:34'
          Other 0x14ebd3d0: traits: 8388608, {{282.0, 0.0}, {33.0, 20.0}}, label: '100% battery power, Charging'
Path to element:
 →Application 0x14e7e300: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 0x14ea2c00
  Output: {
    Application 0x14e7e300: {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
  }
```

Comment: What does the Accessibility Inspector tell you? (Spotlight search for it then hover over your element in the simulator.)

Comment: I can see the textView but not the view containing it. Should I search for a specific field in the inspector? In general, Is there any way to access a generic UIView like you do with buttons, sliders, static text...

Comment: according to the accessibility Inspector, with app.staticText["MyLabel"] I'm accessing an element accessibilityRoleDescription=text and accessibilityRole=AXStaticText, not the textView itself (which has accessibilityValue = <nil>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to log output you've provided there is no view with `MyView` identifier.
You can set it with a help of `accessibilityIdentifier` property.

Answer (score 13):

Do you have access to another elements in your app? Can you successfully tap on smth?
You can see your app hierarchy by

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
print(app.debugDescription)
```

and try to understand where is your view and what elementtype it is (eg it can be .otherElement :))

Comment: I've done it already and I can see in the tree that there is a parent view but I cannot access it for tapping. It looks like there is no way to get an XCUIElementQuery object for that container view. Do you know if there is any way to access the parent view of the label?

Comment: I don`t know the way to get parent of some element. Have you tried to set accessibilityId to your UIView?  Also, like a way to check that you get needed otherElement you can debug it like

Comment: ...  Also, like a way to check that you get needed otherElement you can debug it like ` for entry in app.otherElements { print(entry.textViews.elementBoundByIndex(0).staticTexts["MyLbl"].label)}` its for hierarchy CustomUIView-UITextView-Label. If the research like this give you result - you absolutely can set accId to your customUIView and get it like app.otherElement[your id of custom uiView

Comment: I tried but when I activate the accessibility flag on the view in Storyboard I get that behaviour reported in the post

Comment: I think it's a problem of Xcode configuration: on another system is working.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem but was lucky to notice that my custom view would show up in the UI test of a `ViewController` but it would be absent from  another.

It turns out, my custom view was missing the `width` constraint in the `ViewController` where it was not showing on the UI tests. After adding the constraint, it showed up in my tests.